# SoftLayer BareMetal Server : SoftLayer_Hardware/{bmserverID}/rebootSoft.json

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

SoftLayer_Hardware/{bmserverID}/rebootSoft.json

Above REST API is working and reboot of bare metal server is success.

After some time if we invoke stop (SoftLayer_Hardware/{bmserverID}/powerOff) OR reboot we are getting the error message as :

{"error":"Cannot issue command at this time.  A Remote management command has recently been issued for server ..","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

Answer (score 1):

This is an exception expected, according to [SoftLayer_Hardware::rebootSoft](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/rebootSoft) method's overview:

> "Remote management commands are unable to be issued within 20 minutes
>   of issuing a successful soft reboot in order to avoid server failure.
>   Remote management commands include: rebootSoft rebootHard powerOn
>   powerOff powerCycle"

Comment: I agree with this but is there any other api which will give information that Remote management commands will work after 20 minutes.  20 minutes is approximate time and it can complete within less time or more time.

Comment: There is no any api method which provide information when the remote management commands could be used. but you can trying to ping the server, you can verify with it. Also there exists a method to issues a ping command: [SoftLayer_Hardware::Ping](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/ping)